# ActiveMQ & built-in Jetty: how to redirect HTTP to HTTPS? And how to signal which protocol to use?

Tags: activemq-classic, embedded-jetty

I have modified the admin console of ActiveMQ, i.e. the built-in Jetty, to use HTTPS instead of plain HTTP. However, two (albeit minor) issues remain:

1. I only managed to disable the HTTP port and enable the HTTPS port as suggested in the `jetty.xml` file:

```xml
<list>
<!--
    Default:  Enable this connector if you wish to use http with web console
->
<bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
    <!- see the jettyPort bean ->
    <property name="host" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.host']}" />
    <property name="port" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.port']}" />
</bean>
<!- -->
<!--
    Enable this connector if you wish to use https with web console
-->
<bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
            <property name="keyStorePath" value="${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="password" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="port" value="8162" />
</bean>
```

I would have preferred to leave the HTTP port active but use it to redirect HTTP calls to HTTPS. Can one do that and if so, how? I found no documentation describing this.

2. If one looks at the log at startup one gets a line

```
...
2022-11-23 17:56:04,836 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8162/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2022-11-23 17:56:04,836 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8162/api/jolokia/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
...
```

I.e. the URL displayed obviously picks up the correct port (8162 which I had changed from the default 8161 when switching to HTTPS) but displays the wrong protocol ("http") which is not correct. HTTP is not served any more, only HTTPS.

Can one tweak that as well so that the log also displays the correct protocol, i.e `https://0.0.0.0:8162/...`.

Comment: You should probably narrow down your question to just one issue. Currently you have two issues which, although related, are distinct. Your question is liable to be closed for this reason.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Specify your (http connector) `HttpConfiguration` properly with regards to `securePort` and `secureScheme`.

Then add the `SecureRedirectHandler` somewhere early in your Jetty Handler tree.